# assigning dynamic variables to reshape idvar

Tags: r, shiny, reshape

My data frame:

```
structure(list(NEWSEC = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", 
"A2"), tiles = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("1st", 
"2nd", "3rd", "4th"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), AVG = c(360, 
594, 868, 1534, 349, 592, 861)), .Names = c("NEWSEC", "tiles", 
"AVG"), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

It looks like this:

```
  NEWSEC tiles  AVG
1     A1   1st  360
2     A1   2nd  594
3     A1   3rd  868
4     A1   4th 1534
5     A2   1st  349
6     A2   2nd  592
7     A2   3rd  861
```

When I use reshape function from base R

```
reshape(df, idvar = "NEWSEC", timevar = "tiles", direction = "wide")
```

This works perfectly well...but my data frame is generated dynamically through a shiny application input where instead of NEWSEC I could select MARKET or CATEGORY.  Normally I assign the input variable to an object and refer the object in my function. Example:

```
sec <- input$colvar
```

However, when I try similar approach with reshape it isn't working.  My code so far:

```
reshape(df, idvar = sec, timevar = "tiles", direction = "wide").
```

I have also tried pasting the variable sec with quotes but didn't work.

```
reshape(df, idvar = paste(""",sec,""", sep = "), timevar = "tiles", direction = "wide").
```

I don't know if this is right...but just tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of code is correct

```
sec <- input$colvar
reshape(df, idvar = sec, timevar = "tiles", direction = "wide")
```

provided that you do this operations within a reactive context (`reactive`/`render*` functions) and provided that `df` already has these two new columns.

However, you dynamically add these two variables to your data frame `df`, so you have to do it within some `reactive`/`eventReactive` function, as for instance:

```
data <- reactive({
    # let's pretend that this only happens when some conditions are met
    new <- df
    new$Market <- gl(n = 2, k = 4, length = 7, labels = c("Market1", "Market2"))
    new$Category <- gl(n = 2, k = 4, length = 7, labels = c("Cat1", "Cat2"))
    new
  })
```

Say, now you want to reshape this new dynamic dataframe according to the selected id variable and then render it as a table. To do so you have to use `renderTable` function and access your new dataframe via `data()`.

```
output$new <- renderTable({
    # access dynamic data frame "data" via "data()"
    sec <- input$colvar 
    reshape(data(), idvar = sec, timevar = "tiles", direction = "wide")
  })
```

---

**Full example:**

```
library(shiny)

df <- structure(list(NEWSEC = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", 
                          "A2"), tiles = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L),
                          .Label = c("1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th"),
                          class = c("ordered", "factor")), 
                          AVG = c(360,594, 868, 1534, 349, 592, 861)), 
                          .Names = c("NEWSEC", "tiles", "AVG"), 
                          row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4, 
           selectInput("colvar", "Variable:", 
                        choices = c("NEWSEC", "Market", "Category"))
    ),
    column(8, 
           h4("old"), tableOutput("old")
    ),
    h4("new"), tableOutput("new"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  # dynamic data frame 
  data <- reactive({
    new <- df
    new$Market <- gl(n = 2, k = 4, length = 7, labels = c("Market1", "Market2"))
    new$Category <- gl(n = 2, k = 4, length = 7, labels = c("Cat1", "Cat2"))
    new
  })

  output$old <- renderTable({
    # access dynamic data frame "data" via "data()"
    data()
  })

  output$new <- renderTable({
    # access dynamic data frame "data" via "data()"
    sec <- input$colvar 
    reshape(data(), idvar = sec, timevar = "tiles", direction = "wide")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer.  I figured that it works.  Since my application has too many number of inputs and filters and supporting files, I missed it.  Thanks a ton again.